# I've edited my deleted answer to make it clearer, but it's still deleted

Tags: support, deleted-answers, undelete-request

The questioner didn't understand my answer, so a moderator deleted it.  I've since edited by answer to connect the final pair of dots and make it crystal clear, but it is still deleted.  Can it be undeleted?

The question can be seen at [Why do I have to press Ctrl+D twice to close stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162914/why-do-i-have-to-press-ctrld-twice-to-close-stdin/19058876#19058876) .

None of the earlier answers got it completely right, and the questioner seems to believe that nobody has really answered his question

Comment: When you want a post undeleted then flag for moderator attention and explain the matter.

Comment: Why are you using a different account to post this on meta?

Comment: @juergend user with less than 15 rep can't flag so it's a legitimate request here.

Answer (score 11):

I undeleted the answer you point to. We're not notified if a deleted answer is edited, so otherwise you'd need to flag us for this so that we can undelete it.

I believe part of the reason why this was deleted was that you copied and pasted the same answer to two different questions, which gets flagged by the system, and [one of those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369170/why-do-i-have-to-type-ctrl-d-twice/19058817#19058817) had the asker stating that your answer didn't apply to the question asked. We commonly see people shotgunning answers by pasting them across many only tangentially related questions, so it may have looked like this was happening again.

To avoid this in the future, I'd recommend writing each answer to target the exact question being asked in that instance. If two questions really can have the exact same answer, one might be a candidate for being closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: Are there a bunch of comments that were deleted from the post? I'm trying to square the assertions that Ronald was making.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - No, and neither were any deleted from the other question that I can tell.

Answer (score 7):

Flag it and explain why it should be undeleted.

Comment: User with less than 15 rep can't flag.